# C# SMTPClient sending attachment which locates in a url

Tags: c#, smtpclient, attachment

In C#,How can i add an attachment which locates in a remote url(Ex:http://www.mydomain.com/attahments/sample.pdf)  ?

I dont see that kind of overload for Attachment class constructor.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could download the file to your local system using one of the `Download*` methods of the [System.Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class, and then attach it to your mail message.

I don't know how to attach the response stream of the webclient to the mailmessage attachment directly without saving the file to disk. Should be possible, although not according to [this resource](http://www.systemwebmail.com/faq/2.3.aspx).